# Jenkins Pipeline Fails to load Build parameter (Git parameter plugin)

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to build job with build parameters in Jenkins pipeline.

1. Declared a variable in Git parameter plugin
2. Try to access branch name in script

Unfortunately job is unable to list the branches it is throwing java exception error.

Git parameter plugin configuration

GIT parameter plugin
[image]

Pipeline script 
[image]

Error on Triggering of job.
Error in Build
[image]

Java exception
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) 
In your Jenkins job configuration tick/select 
**This project is parameterized** > **Add Parameter** > **String Parameter**

Then in Jenkinsfile I believe you should be able to reference your parameter eg.

```
branches: [[name: '*/' + PARAMETER_NAME ]],
```

Answer (score 1):

add Branch Filter in Git Parmeter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me.

1) Add git parameter 
[Add git parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kab8W.png)

2) Call the variable in script and in configuration

[Pass same variable name as defined earlier in branch section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9N9K.png)